# Scroll-Jacking Issue: How do you restore free-scroll to the rest of the body after you've scrolled through each slide?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I need to incorporate a scroll-jacking functionality into a website. Users will scroll through 'slides'(the scroll-jacked portion), and once they get through all the slides, they'll be able to go back to free-scroll through the rest of the site content.

Here is the code that I wrote:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Scroll-Jackin'</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Arial', 'san-serif'; }
   .free-scroll{ overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
   .main-wrap{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }
   .scroll-wrap{ height: 100%; }
   .slide{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 0; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transition: height .9s ease-in-out;
    background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 148px 150px; background-position: center center; }
   .slide:nth-child(1){ background-color: #000; color: #fff; z-index: 10; }
   .slide:nth-child(2){ background-color: blue; z-index: 9; }
   .slide:nth-child(3){ background-color: magenta; z-index: 8; }
   .active.slide{ height: 100%; }
   .body-wrap{ width: 100%; height: auto; background-color: #eee; z-index: 10; top: -100%; }
   .content { margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; padding: 50px; }
    .content p{ font-size: 2.5em; }
   /*.content{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }*/
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="main-wrap">
   <div class="scroll-wrap">
    <div class="slide active" style="background-image:url('img/logo-01.png');"></div>
    <div class="slide active" style="background-image:url('img/logo-01.png');"></div>
    <div class="slide active" style="background-image:url('img/logo-01.png');"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="body-wrap">
    <div class="content">
     <h1>This is some body content.</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vitae tempus metus, eget efficitur justo. Etiam faucibus lobortis nibh. Sed dapibus justo nec orci imperdiet, a laoreet urna tincidunt. Nullam ex magna, congue vel leo ut, vestibulum elementum augue. Aenean in leo et leo elementum facilisis. Integer vel scelerisque sapien, vel efficitur leo. Morbi hendrerit quam urna, sed tincidunt sem lacinia sit amet. Nam viverra diam ac ultrices ullamcorper.
     <br><br/> 
     Fusce vehicula diam sed pellentesque consequat. Duis non tellus ex. Nam nec tincidunt diam. Curabitur dictum rhoncus libero. Sed orci purus, tristique dignissim ligula non, mollis blandit arcu. Nullam sed ornare ex, vitae gravida nulla. Nunc porttitor placerat mauris vitae ullamcorper. Nunc sit amet velit a sapien pellentesque congue. Proin rhoncus nec ipsum vitae posuere. Praesent suscipit vestibulum lectus quis vehicula.
     <br><br/> 
     Fusce vehicula diam sed pellentesque consequat. Duis non tellus ex. Nam nec tincidunt diam. Curabitur dictum rhoncus libero. Sed orci purus, tristique dignissim ligula non, mollis blandit arcu. Nullam sed ornare ex, vitae gravida nulla. Nunc porttitor placerat mauris vitae ullamcorper. Nunc sit amet velit a sapien pellentesque congue. Proin rhoncus nec ipsum vitae posuere. Praesent suscipit vestibulum lectus quis vehicula.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var delta = 0,
     currentSlideIndex = 0,
     scrollThreshold = 30,
     slides = $('.slide'),
     numSlides = $('.slide').length,
     slidesLeft = numSlides - currentSlideIndex;

    function elementScroll(e) {
       console.log(Math.abs(delta));
       // This is when you're scrolling up.
       if(e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
         delta--; 
         if (Math.abs(delta) >= scrollThreshold) {
            prevSlide();
         }
       }else{
        delta++;
         if (delta >= scrollThreshold) {
           nextSlide();
         }
       }
       return false;
    }
    function showSlide() {
       // Mousewheel count is being reset to zero to show each slide one by one.
       delta = 0;
       slides.each(function(i, slide) {
         $(slide).toggleClass('active', (i >= currentSlideIndex));
       });
    }
    function prevSlide() {
     // This is when you're scrolling down.
       currentSlideIndex--;
       if (currentSlideIndex < 0) {
         currentSlideIndex = 0;
       }
       showSlide();
    }
    function nextSlide() {
       currentSlideIndex++;
       if (currentSlideIndex > numSlides) {
         currentSlideIndex = numSlides;
       }
       showSlide();
    }
    $(window).on({'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll}, function(){
     if(currentSlideIndex = 3){
      $('body').addClass('free-scroll');
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

So far, the 'slides' are working the way that I need them to. I just need to restore the free-scrolling when the user gets to the content after the slides. What am I missing?

Comment: I dropped all of your code in js fiddle, but it fails to run at all. Can you put together a jsfiddle that shows your code working as you've described, so that I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding! Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eevnoc4g/

Comment: I can't get it to run from work. We have a very locked down network. I'll try it when I get home tonight.

Comment: Just seeing this now. Thanks again! Also, if it helps, i'm basically trying to re-create the functionality on the homepage of the HUGE Inc. website here: http://hugeinc.com . I'll also be working on this as well, so if I happen to solve it, I'll let you know.

Comment: I was not able to get your jsfiddle sample working. It only shows a black screen with white text that states ,"Testing". I tested it in IE11 and FF.